# Spring JPA one to many

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mapping, entity

I have two entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Registration")
public class Registration{

   @Id
   private UUID uuid;

   @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="registration", nullable = false)
   private List<Payment> payment;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="Payment")
public class Payment {

   @Id
   private UUID uuid;

   /*@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Registration.class)  <-- MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity
   private Registration registration;*/
}
```

This entities create two tables :

```
TABLE `registration` (
 `uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`))

TABLE `payment` (
 `uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
 `registration` binary(16) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_jgemihcy9uethvoe3l7mx2bih` FOREIGN KEY (`registration`)           REFERENCES `registration` (`uuid`))
```

I'm using Rest Service. I can access to

> registration.payment

but not

> payment.registration

why ? I need a relation oneToMany bidirectionnal ?

Comment: From your entity definition, there is no relationship between payment and registration actually, what you really want?

Comment: This is a mistake from me. I'm using controller with rest service to access json object. I can't access : payment.registration. What is the best way please ?

Comment: Yes, you should add `ManyToOne` to registration here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the *payment.registration* @ManyToOne relationship if you use it in your code.

Take into account that JPA allows you to map a SQL database model to an object oriented one. Once you have the mapping between your objects and your database, you always work at the object level. That's why, although you have the relationship in the database, your Payment object doesn't know anything about it unless you map it to an attribute.

Of course it applies when you are using you data model objects or performing JPQL or Criteria queries. If you use native queries you have access to the database model as it is.

Comment: Add @ManyToOne return : `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: `Payment column: registration (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Comment: You have to add the _mappedBy_ attribute in your _@OneToMany_ annotation to make the relationship bidirectional.